# Algos - Delete Extremes From A List of Integers in Python?

Tags: python, list, loops, recursion

I want to eliminate extremes from a list of integers in Python. I'd say that my problem is one of design. Here's what I cooked up so far:

```
listToTest = [120,130,140,160,200]

def function(l):
    length = len(l)
    for x in xrange(0,length - 1):
        if l[x] < (l[x+1] - l[x]) * 4:
            l.remove(l[x+1])
    return l

print function(listToTest)
```

So the output of this should be: 120,130,140,160 without 200, since that's way too far ahead from the others.

And this works, given 200 is the last one or there's only one extreme. Though, it gets problematic with a list like this:

```
listToTest = [120,200,130,140,160,200]
```

Or

```
listToTest = [120,130,140,160,200,140,130,120,200]
```

So, the output for the last list should be: 120,130,140,160,140,130,120. 200 should be gone, since it's a lot bigger than the "usual", which revolved around ~130-140.
To illustrate it, here's an image:
[image]
Obviously, my method doesn't work. Some thoughts:
- I need to somehow do a comparison between x and x+1, see if the next two pairs have a bigger difference than the last pair, then if it does, the pair that has a bigger difference should have one element eliminated (the biggest one), then, recursively do this again. I think I should also have an "acceptable difference", so it knows when the difference is acceptable and not break the recursivity so I end up with only 2 values.

I tried writting it, but no luck so far.

Answer (score 4):

You can use statistics here, eliminating values that fall beyond n standard deviations from the mean:

```
import numpy as np
test = [120,130,140,160,200,140,130,120,200]
n = 1
output = [x for x in test if abs(x - np.mean(test)) < np.std(test) * n]
# output is [120, 130, 140, 160, 140, 130, 120]
```

Comment: I appreciate the contribution - it works! Though, could you provide some documentation on this? I really want to write my own, to understand how it works, that's my end goal.

Comment: The output above is a list comprehension which keeps a value only if it falls within 1 standard deviation of the mean, getting rid of vlaues which are above or below 1 standard deviation. If n is set to 2, then it'll get rid of values which are above or below 2 standard deviations of the mean. abs(x - np.mean(test)) calculates how far a value is from the average. np.std(test) calculates the [standard deviation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation) assuming a normal distribution.

Comment: This is a better (simpler) answer than mine if you have a small dataset that you can read in its entirety before performing the calculation .

Comment: Thanks, I get it! Reading more on it now.

Comment: This is not a moving algorithm though, depending on your use-case it can be more or less accurate.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem statement is not clear. If you simply want to remove the max and min then that is a simple

```
O(N) with  2 extra memory- which is O(1)
```

operation.  This is achieved by retaining the current min/max value and comparing it to each entry in the list in turn.

If you want the min/max K items it is still

```
 O(N + KlogK)  with O(k) extra memory
```

operation.  This is achieved by two priorityqueue's of size K: one for the mins, one for the max's.

Or did you intend a different output/outcome from your algorithm?

**UPDATE** the OP has updated the question: it appears they want a moving (/windowed) average and to delete outliers.

The following is an **online** algorithm  -i.e. it can handle streaming data  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_algorithm

We can retain a moving average: let's say you keep K entries for the average.

Then create a linked list of size K  and a pointer to the head and tail.  Now: handling items within the first K entries needs to be thought out separately. After the first K *retained* items the algo can proceed as follows:
   check the next item in the input list against the running k-average. If the value exceeds the acceptable ratio threshold then put its list index into a separate "deletion queue" list. Otherwise: update the running windowed sum as follows:

- (a) remove the head entry from the linked list and subtract its value from the running sum
- (b) add the latest list entry as the tail of the linked list and add its value to the running sum
  (c) recalculate the running average as the running sum /K

Now: how to handle the first K entries? - i.e. before we have a properly initialized running sum?

You will need to make some hard-coded decisions here.  A possibility:

- run through all first K+2D (D << K) entries.
- Keep d max/min values
- Remove the d (<< K) max/min values from that list

Comment: OK so it appears you are looking for a Windowing function to create a moving average: and if a given new value exceeds that average by .. what.. a certain relative fraction? .. then it gets removed. Does that capture your intent?

Comment: Sounds great! Yes, that sums it up, I think!

Comment: I see your logic and from what I understand, it works, though @trans has provided a solution, I really want to understand the workings behind it. Will continue with him, thanks!

Comment: The solution from @trans works fine if you have the option to read the entire dataset into memory FIRST.  My solution is an "online" solution. You can look up what that means:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_algorithm

Comment: I didn't think of that. The issue then is that my algorythm gets its data from me, or well, the list is generated by some counts. :) I'm not looking for usability / portability here.

Comment: If you want an online solution, there are all kinds of sophisticated methods, generally classified as "anomaly detection" algorithms.